# Process each element in a list for each line from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a file that includes IP, hostname, protocol and a series of ports for each IP that I want to generate configs for.  How do I process each element in a list for each line?

From log file:

```
ip1,hostname,protocol,port_1,port_2,port_n...
ip2,hostname,protocol,port_1,port_2,port_n...
ip3,hostname,protocol,port_1,port_2,port_n...
```

I have tried so far:

```
for each_line in port:
    print(f"object-service service {each_line}")
```

result:

```
object-service service 443, 9993
object-service service 443, 3389, 445
object-service service 443, 22, 3389, 23
object-service service 3389, 445, 443
object-service service 443, 3389, 445
```

Even specifying the first line only:

```
for each_line in port[0]:
    print(f"object-service service {each_line}")
```

The result is really off:

```
object-service service 4
object-service service 4
object-service service 3
object-service service ,
object-service service  
object-service service 9
object-service service 9
object-service service 9
object-service service 3
```

extracted ports:

```
443, 9993
443, 3389, 445
443, 22, 3389, 23
3389, 445, 443
443, 3389, 445
```

Expected result:

```
line 1
 print port 443
 print port 9993
line 2
 print port 443
 print port 3389
 print port 445
line n...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you already tried? This should be dead simple- just loop over each list of ports and print. Maybe there's something more complicated that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: @ wjandrea, I have a hard time with the loop to iterate each element in each line.  Perphaps you can shed some lights?

Comment: I have some idea of what you're looking for, but it would be easier to explain if you provide what you've already got. Please add it to the question. See [mre] for what you should include.

Comment: @ wjandrea, I have updated the question with loops that I have tried so far.

Comment: Let me give this a try and update the question.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @wjandrea How would I go about applying your suggested solution to each of the IP on each line?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to like, break the IP into octets?

Comment: From my log, I would like to generate a config file for all the IP and the ports (at the end of the line).  Perhaps I should edit so you can see the expected result?

Comment: Please ask a new question about that, and send me the link so I can take a look.

Comment: Sure, that would be great.  I'd appreciate the prompt response.

Comment: @wjandrea, I have just posted the question.  Here's the link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66380472/generate-network-configurations-from-log-file).  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split each string into each port, then print each one.

And you can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the line number.

```
# Example data
port_strings = [
    '443, 9993',
    '443, 3389, 445',
    '443, 22, 3389, 23',
    '3389, 445, 443',
    '443, 3389, 445']

for i, port_string in enumerate(port_strings, 1):
    print('line', i)
    for port in port_string.split(', '):
        print(' print port', port)
```

Output:

```
line 1
 print port 443
 print port 9993
line 2
 print port 443
 print port 3389
 print port 445
line 3
 print port 443
 print port 22
 print port 3389
 print port 23
line 4
 print port 3389
 print port 445
 print port 443
line 5
 print port 443
 print port 3389
 print port 445
```